# How to remove class in vue.js

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

As I am new to Vue.js, can anyone help me in how to remove class from element similarly like we do in JQuery.

```
$('.class1').removeClass("class2");
```

Comment: learn more about class binding here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From what is written in their documentation I'd say it something you should not do in your code.

Instead, your CSS classes should be bounded to properties and presence of a class should be determined by property value.

Example (from docs):

```
<div v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }"></div>
```

The above syntax means the presence of the `active` class will be determined by the truthiness of the data property `isActive` (if `isActive IS true` - class will be there).

You can have multiple classes toggled by having more fields in the object. In addition, the `v-bind:class` directive can also co-exist with the plain class attribute. So given the following template:

```
<div class="static"
     v-bind:class="{ active: isActive, 'text-danger': hasError }">
</div>
```

And the following data:

```
data: {
  isActive: true,
  hasError: false
}
```

It will render:

```
<div class="static active"></div>
```

When `isActive` or `hasError` changes, the class list will be updated accordingly. For example, if `hasError` becomes true, the class list will become `static active text-danger`.

I believe that's the right way to go :) Please check [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) for more details.

If for some reason you need to remove a class you could add jQuery as a dependency to your app and use it (but it's not preferable).

Happy hacking :)

Answer (score 1):

Given you have a this element

```
<div id="randomDiv">
  <p :style="{backgroundColor:color}" @click="updateBackgroundColor(color)">{{obj.name}}</p>
</div>
```

the **:style** allows you to add a style to the element, in this case it is the **backgroundColor** style we are adding, it can be anything, and you can see that has a value of color which comes the Vue object bellow. This is initially set to yellow in the **vm = new Vue()** object. This object also has a function called **updateBackgroundColor** which carries out the update. The color is passed into this function from the **@click** in the element.

```
var obj = {
  "name": "Curtis",
}


var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#randomDiv',
  data: function (){
    return  {
        obj,
        color: 'yellow',
    }
  },
  methods: {
        updateBackgroundColor: function (color) {
        console.log(color);
          if(color === "yellow"){
            this.$set(this.$data, 'color', 'red');
          }
          else{
            this.$set(this.$data, 'color', 'yellow');
          }
        }
    }
});
```

i have also pasted this in JsFiddle for you to see.

[https://jsfiddle.net/ifelabolz/todqxteh/1044/][1]

Answer (score 0):

My case show/hide modal by add CSS

In element tag html

```
<a href="#" class="copyright" v-on:click="show()">Add Line For Ad</a>

<modal name="qrcode">
 MODAL IS SHOW NOW!!.
</modal>
```

And

```
export default {
  methods: {
    show: function() {
      this.$modal.show("qrcode");
    },
    hide() {
      this.$modal.hide("qrcode");
    },
    toggleBodyClass(className) {
      const el = document.body;
      // debugger;
      el.classList.remove(className);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.toggleBodyClass("v--modal");
  }
};
```

This CSS

```
.v--modal {
  background: red;
}
```

Hope this help.